# How to create standard account using stripe API

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am working for development payouts system. Then I should create standard account for every user.
but it is not able to do, right now.
I used this one.

```
const pickerAccount = await stripe.accounts.create({
          type: 'standard',
          email: params.email,
          capabilities: {
            card_payments: {requested: true},
            transfers: {requested: true},
          },
        });
```

Then it returns "you cannot create standard connected account with capabilities via api"

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For Standard Connect you'd use the Connect Onboarding flow: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-shipping_address_collection

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when doing almost the same. Apparently you just can't include the "capabilities" param in the request and the enabled capabilities for standard accounts are managed from the dashboard. Like you'd need to just do:

```
const pickerAccount = await stripe.accounts.create({
      type: 'standard',
      email: params.email,
    });
```